# Flutter: Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly. Error launching application on I2019

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging, adb

I'm trying to run my Flutter app on my physical device, it is a mobile phone named IQOO 9 SE but I keep getting this error. The app runs on other physical devices but the problem arises only on my device.
Is there a way to solve this problem.

```
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:615:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1209:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
#3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
          <asynchronous suspension>
#4      CommandRunner.runCommand
package:args/command_runner.dart:209
           <asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
#6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
         <asynchronous suspension>
#7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
#8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
#9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
#10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

This is what I get in the debug console if I run it with Capturing Logs.

First I tried flutter clean and flutter pub get again.

I also tried killing the adb server and restarting it again.

I tried changing the package name of my app and running it.

After trying all that I realised the problem is with my phone so I performed a factory reset and still I got the same issue.

Comment: Please provide full log. Please provide your device's android os version as well

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cC2Jmis7k2XTSAowduaakvRiRx-MWXai/view?usp=sharing -> This is the link for the log file and my Android OS Version is 13. @HardikMehta

Comment: Please check this thread : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117019 Related to Vivo devices like funtouch OS